# How to execute Unit Test with Sonar Qube 5.0.1

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, gallio, opencover

I was able to execute Unit test with lower version of Sonarqube but then i upgraded to SonarQube 5.0.1. Then suddenly my Gallio was not working. I found in some blocks that support for gallio was not available in sonarqube 5.0.1
Is there any other way to run unit test and get code coverage in sonarqube 5.0.1 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallio support has been removed from sonar version 4.3 .From now on you have to produce your own test results and import them in sonar. hope this helps.
Please like the comment if you find it useful

Comment: Can you please point me to some help links regarding importing test results into sonar.